# For differents parametrization of the sphere, will we have the same jacobian?

Tags: parametrization, jacobian

I know several parametrization of the sphere as 
$$(x,y,z)=(r\cos\theta \sin\varphi,r\sin\theta \sin\varphi, r\cos \varphi)$$

$$(x,y,z)=(r\sin\varphi, r\cos\theta \cos\varphi, r\cos \varphi\sin\theta )$$

where $\varphi\in [0,\pi]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. The question is : does the jacobian (i.e. the determinant of the jacobian matrix) will depend on the parametrization or not ? i.e. will it be $r\sin^2 \varphi$ always or not ?

Comment: It will depend. You can check it by a direct calculation

Comment: Why would you expect different parameterizations to have the same Jacobian in the first place?